# Select and Unselect buttons

Tags: android

I have a list of text views in which some goal is defined. User can select maximum 3 goals. He can also unselect his selected goal and select another. Currently what I have done is user can select only 3 goals but if user unselect any goal and try to select another goal its not happening.

Here is my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.goalText1:
                if (count <= 2 && isSelected) {
                    goals.add(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                    mGoal1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    count++;
                    isSelected=false;
                    mGoal1.setSelected(true);

                } else {
                    isSelected = true;
                    goals.remove(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                    mGoal1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    mGoal1.setSelected(false);

                }
                break;

            case R.id.goalText2:

                if (count <= 2 && isSelected) {
                    goals.add(mGoal2.getText().toString());
                    mGoal2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    count++;
                    mGoal2.setSelected(true);
                    isSelected=false;
                } else {
                    isSelected = true;
                    goals.remove(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                    mGoal2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    mGoal2.setSelected(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "select upto 3 fitness goals only " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;

            case R.id.goalText3:

                if (count <= 2 && isSelected) {
                    goals.add(mGoal3.getText().toString());
                    mGoal3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    count++;
                    mGoal3.setSelected(true);
                    isSelected=false;
                } else {
                    isSelected = true;
                    goals.remove(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                    mGoal3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    mGoal3.setSelected(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "select upto 3 fitness goals only " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;

            case R.id.goalText4:

                if (count <= 2 && isSelected) {
                    goals.add(mGoal4.getText().toString());
                    mGoal4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    count++;
                    mGoal4.setSelected(true);
                    isSelected=false;
                } else {
                    isSelected = true;
                    goals.remove(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                    mGoal4.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    mGoal4.setSelected(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "select upto 3 fitness goals only " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
```

Comment: try somthing like that:

        if (count > 0)
            --count;

in the else branch

Comment: @gaurav tiwari you are checking value from only one veriable as isSelected so it will not help you and therefore your above code is going in wring direction, you should use list and add values in it and later you need to check on click as it is exist in list or not and manage it

Comment: @Vickyexpert I didn't understand can you gave me some example

Comment: @canisLupusLupus I tried to put the if condition in else part but now my counter is not increasing. I tried something like this  else {
                        if(count>0){
                            count--;                      mGoal1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                            mGoal1.setSelected(false);
                            isSelected = true;

Comment: @gauravtiwari check below my answer and apply it for one goal only first and check if it works properly then apply for all goals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First apply this logic for first goal and check if it is working or not then you can apply for all goal with little modifications like change id and all,

```
    case R.id.goalText1:
            if (goals.size <= 2 && ! mGoal1.isSelected()) 
            {
                goals.add(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                mGoal1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                mGoal1.setSelected(true);

            } else {
                goals.remove(mGoal1.getText().toString());
                mGoal1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                mGoal1.setSelected(false);

            }
            break;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this save my lot of time.

Comment: Welcome ! Enjoy Your coding